# pg:backups restore gets into pending status

Tags: heroku, restore, pg, backups

I was using Heroku PGbackups add-on for backup copying of DB from one Heroku app into another Heroku app. But after PGbackups migration and removal of their add-on, I moved these commands to using new commands according to instructions. 
But I am now encountering an issue with this process: sometimes pg:backups restore gets into pending status. The DB is cleared but the backup doesn't copy/restore and just stucks with 'pending'.

Here is what I got when checking the status of pg:backups [image: pg status]

At this time the Db was not overloaded with connections: 
[image: PG info]

Then I used pg:wait command and previous requests failed and the new ones worked fine and did not get into pending [image: pg:wait command]

But I am not sure if this will happen again.

I would be very grateful if you explain me what the reason might be and how to fix the issue.
Thanks in advance for your time and help.